# cant call batch file over network

Tags: vb.net, batch-file

I am trying to call a bat file that is within a network drive. I think that this line of code is causing the issue:

```
Call Shell(Environ$("COMSPEC") & " /c \\filepath\hello.bat", vbNormalFocus)
```

This runs fine on my own machine, but as soon as I go onto the network it does not work. Is it something to do with the **/c** bit?

Comment: The path `\filepath\hello.bat` looks wrong - is that what you're really using?  A path on a remote server `foo` would look like `\\foo\...`

Comment: Perhaps you could (temporarily) change the `Call Shell` to an echo and see what string is actually being used as the command.

Comment: Are you entirely sure it's not due to antivirus or intrusion prevention software? Remote execution of a batch file would certainly be seen as a threat.

Answer (score 0):

Are the network paths are defined in your shell environment?  You need to might need to use full UNC paths.

Comment: If you defined F: as \\Myserver\myShare then F:\mybatch.cmd is \\myserver\myshare\mybatch.cmd

Comment: Oh hold on I am getting the error that UNC paths are NOT supported - leans to the anti virus idea I think - now what? any ideas?

Comment: What version of windows are you using?  Try it from a normal command prompt.  cmd /c \\server\share\filename.cmd and see if it runs.  Remember to put quotes around it if you have a space.

Comment: OK solved it - the issue was in the names I was using the the file path and the folder tree - so '\\Test_File' was a no go '\\TestFile' worked - thing is how do you reference a file with either a space or _?

Comment: Put the path in double quotes.  cmd /c "\\server\share\file with space"

Comment: my word - something so simple - clearly showing (once again) my lack of knowledge in this area - thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

with this code you can get the unc path information from drives in your system.

```
Sub SampleUNC()


    Dim uncPaths As Dictionary(Of String, String)
    Dim infoUnc As String = String.Empty

    'Get Unc Drives info in your system
    uncPaths = GetUncDrivePaths()

    For Each kvp As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In uncPaths

        'X:   \\MyServer\Software\
        'Y:   \\MyServer\Documents\

        Debug.WriteLine(kvp.Key & "  " & kvp.Value)

    Next

    'get the Unc path from the mapped drive   \\MyServer\Documents\
    infoUnc = GetUncPath("Y:")

    MsgBox(infoUnc)

End Sub


Public Shared Function GetUncDrivePaths() As Dictionary(Of String, String)

    Dim uncDictionary As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

    Try

        Dim dis As DriveInfo() = DriveInfo.GetDrives()

        For Each di As DriveInfo In dis
            If di.DriveType = DriveType.Network Then

                Dim dir As DirectoryInfo = di.RootDirectory

                Dim name As String = dir.FullName.Substring(0, 2)
                Dim realPath As String = GetUNCPath(name)

                uncDictionary.Add(name, realPath)

                ' "x:"

                'MessageBox.Show(GetUNCPath(dir.FullName.Substring(0, 2)))

            End If
        Next

    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw
    End Try

    Return uncDictionary

End Function

Public Shared Function GetUncPath(ByVal path As String) As String

    Try

        If path.StartsWith("\\") Then
            Return path
        End If

        Dim mo As New ManagementObject()
        mo.Path = New ManagementPath(String.Format("Win32_LogicalDisk='{0}'", path))

        'DriveType 4 = Network Drive
        If Convert.ToUInt32(mo("DriveType")) = 4 Then
            Return Convert.ToString(mo("ProviderName"))
        Else
            Return path
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception

        Throw

    Finally


    End Try


End Function
```